# node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵFactoryDeclaration' - Angular 9

Tags: node.js, angular, visual-studio, npm, webpack-dev-server

I am having hundreds of errors on npm start/ng serve for an angular app that is running on Angular 9, the project is loading from npm global registry some components and some other private components for a private feed registry that we got internally, I can run npm install successfully with no errors, I've tried deleting **packages-lock.json** file and **node_module** folders with no luck

**NG Version**

Angular CLI: 9.1.15
Node: 14.7.0
OS: win32 x64

```
Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.901.15
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.901.15
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.901.15
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.901.15
@angular-devkit/core              9.1.15
@angular-devkit/schematics        9.1.15
@angular/cdk                      12.2.13
@angular/cli                      9.1.15
@angular/material                 11.2.13
@ngtools/webpack                  9.1.15
@schematics/angular               9.1.15
@schematics/update                0.901.15
rxjs                              6.5.5
typescript                        3.8.3
webpack                           4.42.0
```

**NPM Version**

```
{
  'public-portal': '0.0.0',
  npm: '6.14.13',
  ares: '1.16.0',
  brotli: '1.0.7',
  cldr: '37.0',
  icu: '67.1',
  llhttp: '2.0.4',
  modules: '83',
  napi: '6',
  nghttp2: '1.41.0',
  node: '14.7.0',
  openssl: '1.1.1g',
  tz: '2020a',
  unicode: '13.0',
  uv: '1.38.1',
  v8: '8.4.371.19-node.12',
  zlib: '1.2.11'
}
```

**Errors Samples on NG Start**

```
ERROR in Unexpected value 'FormioModule in node_modules/@formio/angular/formio.module.d.ts' imported by the module 'FormIOModule in src/app/form-io/form-io.module.ts'. Please add a @NgModule annotation.
Unexpected value 'FormioGrid in node_modules/@formio/angular/grid/grid.module.d.ts' imported by the module 'FormIOModule in src/app/form-io/form-io.module.ts'. Please add a @NgModule annotation.
'formio-grid' is not a known element:


/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵInjectorDeclaration'.



/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵNgModuleDeclaration'.

/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵPipeDeclaration'.
```

Answer (score 0):

turned out, it was the peer dependencies, so instead of npm install, I've used

```
npm ci
```

so that, I don't mess with the dependencies inside the packages-lock.json file and then it worked.